# Is their any Way to create client token for braintree with api in magento 2

Tags: magento2, braintree, token

I would like to generate a client token for brain tree paypal payment as a

response,How can i solve,please any idea.any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call this Library > \Magento\Braintree\Model\Adapter\BraintreeAdapterFactory $bt_adapter in construct.

afterwards,

$bt_adapter = $this->bt_factory->create();
$value = $bt_adapter->generate();

That should generate a client token for you provided that you first made the config in admin for Braintree